# Why my Element is going outside the header element

Tags: html, css, reactjs

There is a div with a class of `favourite` which is not aligning in the header section.
Yes this is a react project but it is edited like a normal project for this question.

```
<div className='header'>
  <img class='profilePhoto' src='./userIcon'></img>
  <div class='brand-logo'>
  </div>
  <div class='favourite'>Favourite</div> <!-- This Favourite is going outisde div.header-->
</div>
```

CSS File:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5rem;
  background: #2475b0;
  position: fixed;
}

.profilePhoto {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 32px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.brand-logo {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.favourite {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  right: 3rem;
}
```

Brand Logo CSS

```
.icon-box {
  background: #eaf0f1;
  width: 19rem;
  height: 75%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.brand-name {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Image Preview:

[image]

Any tip will be helpful.. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please make jsFiddle for your code.

Comment: I think it's because your `brand-logo` taking `100%` height of `header`. Try removing / reducing height from `brand-logo`. Like `profilePhoto` you can place `brand-logo` using abslute position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2875348/ravibagul91

Guys this is happening because `.brand-logo` is taking 100% height!
When I removed:

```
height: 100%
```

then code is working fine...
 I just simply removed flexbox and used position property to align my `.brand-logo`

```
.brand-logo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code in favourite class.

```
    .favourite {
       text-align: right;
       position: relative;
       right: 3rem;
       margin-top: -45px;    
      }
```

Adjust margin-top as your need.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the height of header div

```
.header {
  height: 10rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give position for make your logo in center. Just remove fix height from header and try using padding. Hope will help you.

```css
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
     }

     .header {
      width: 100vw;
      padding: 20px;
      background: #2475b0;
      position: fixed;
     }
```

```html
       <div class='header'>
      <div class='brand-logo'>
       <img class='profilePhoto' src='/userIcon'>
      </div>
      <div class='favourite'>Favourite</div> <!-- This Favourite is  going outisde div.header-->
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add display: inline-block to 3 classes:

```html
.profilePhoto, .brand-logo, .favourite {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and remove position attribute in class favourite. One more, i think you should use 'class' attribute, not 'className' like :

```html
<div className='header'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this just add height and padding.

```
.header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10rem;
  background: #2475b0;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5rem;
  background: #2475b0;
  position: fixed;
}

.profilePhoto {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 32px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.brand-logo {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.favourite {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
    <img class='profilePhoto' src='./userIcon'>
    <div class='favourite'>Favourite</div>
    <div class='brand-logo'></div>
</div>
```